# Science Fiction Book: "cure for death" made everything come back to life

Tags: story-identification

This is taken from a book club site that I belong to, so this is all the info I have.

> Help... need a book title (for Christmas gift)

Description is...

> It may have had FIRE in the title.
>
> Scientists accidentally created a "cure" for death but it made everything come back. Pork chops grew into whole pigs in the supermarket, a little boy thought a guy was Jesus because he watched him come back to life, a guy was lynched and hanged and then hanged over and over because he didn't stay dead. Then there was a goat beast thing the media dubbed the antichrist but it was actually the good guy and the real bad guy was some kind of three headed dragon.

Comment: Could you add a link to site which this was originally pulled from?

Comment: And will you know if it's the right answer since you weren't asking the question?

Comment: TVTropes link: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeathTakesAHoliday

Comment: No, can't link to site as it is a closed Facebook group. I knew it was a long shot. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7):

[Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_(Rodgers_novel)) by Alan Rodgers

Description from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25694391-fire):

> Two countries on the brink of nuclear war. The President is bent on
>   avenging the greatest loss a man can endure: the First Lady. A
>   dangerous religious organization vying to control the fate of the
>   earth. A mysterious virus leading to the resurrection of the dead all
>   over the planet. A bestial nightmare of a creature straight out of
>   Revelation. These are the elements at play in FIRE, an epic novel of
>   the world in what might be its final days.
>
> This fast-paced novel written from the point of view of ordinary
>   people confronting the end of the world is a genuine page-turner. From
>   janitor Ron Hawkins, who's just trying to make it through his college
>   graduation to Luke Munsen, a scientist who wanted to find out dinosaur
>   biology, to an intrepid tabloid reporter, a mad scientist and the
>   President himself, the world has turned upside-down. Our greatest
>   fears are a reality. Even our food is coming back to life ... and
>   attacking!

[Review on amazon](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R3JJDFAVXTWQ2X/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=055328777X) mentions the finding of cure for death:

> A sprawling, apocalyptic novel about three groups of people converging
>   to help save the world from a madman. Nuclear explosions, worldwide
>   panic, and a scientist whose found a cure for...DEATH?

Excerpt:

> "I ain't too sure. When it started out it weren't nothing but a pork
>   chop."
>
> *monkey* was licking his fingers.
>
> *pig* was a great sprawling mass of stringy flesh that sprawled out and all over the table; so large, now, that the mass of it could have
>   filled a basin.
>
> "Really? That weren't nothing but a pork chop?"
>
> "Nuh-uh. Not one bit more when it started out. Give it another day or
>   so and the damned thing'll be a fulll-grown pig."

[The Google book](https://books.google.com/books?id=gM7RCQAAQBAJ)

Comment: Robyn, if you have feedback that this is the right answer (from your Facebook group), you can accept it by clicking the checkmark button on the left. Please do; it shows everyone the mystery was solved and will reward both you and Ayshe with some reputation :)